# ClickOnce equivalent with query parameters

Tags: query-string, clickonce, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 WPF application deployed with ClickOnce. Deployment and update works fine, however, the `ApplicationDeployment` class is not available anymore in .NET 6, which means I can't read the query string given in the startup URL.

Is there an alternative or a workaround, working with .NET 6, that can still be launched with a URL and that can accept query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1:
   Update the VS2022 to the lastest version.
Step-2:
  Project RightClick => Publish => Publish-Tab => Show All => Setting-tab => Options => Allow Url-Paramaters....
Step-3:
  Copy [this file](https://github.com/simmotech/Net6ClickOnce/blob/master/ClickOnceCommandLineTestApp/ClickOnceInfo.cs) code to you app.
Step-4:
  Write Fllowing code:

```
var clickOnceInfo = new ClickOnceInfo();
    if (!clickOnceInfo.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("设计器只能从Web页面启动，无法独立使用");
        return;
    }
    var query = clickOnceInfo.ActivationUri?.Query ?? "QueryEMPTY";
    if (query == "QueryEMPTY")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("参数设置异常,无法启动设计器");
        return;
    }
```